# jQuery - product quantity not changing when I click plus button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery codes. When I click + button, its supposed to increase the value by 1. But somehow its not working. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code.?

**JSFiddle**

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/2APBa/2/). Please view input value using "Inspect element"

**HTML**

```
<div class="showbutton02">
            <form action="/take-away/?add-to-cart=79" class="cart myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus"><input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text"><input type="button" value="+" class="plus"></div>
<div class="linkbtn02"><button type="submit" data-product_id="79" data-product_sku="" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</button></div>            </form>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    $(document).on( 'click', '.plus, .minus', function() {

        // Get values
        var $qty        = $(this).closest('.quantity').find(".qty");
        var currentVal  = parseFloat( $qty.val() );
        var max         = parseFloat( $qty.attr('max') );
        var min         = parseFloat( $qty.attr('min') );
        var step        = $qty.attr('step');

        // Format values
        if ( ! currentVal || currentVal == "" || currentVal == "NaN" ) currentVal = 0;
        if ( max == "" || max == "NaN" ) max = '';
        if ( min == "" || min == "NaN" ) min = 0;
        if ( step == 'any' || step == "" || step == undefined || parseFloat( step ) == "NaN" ) step = 1;

        // Change the value
        if ( $(this).is('.plus') ) {

            if ( max && ( max == currentVal || currentVal > max ) ) {
                $qty.val( max );
            } else {
                $qty.val( currentVal + parseFloat( step ) );
            }

        } else {

            if ( min && ( min==currentVal || currentVal < min ) ) {
                $qty.val( min );
            } else if ( currentVal > 0 ) {
                $qty.val( currentVal - parseFloat( step ) );
            }

        }

        // Trigger change event
        $qty.trigger('change');
    });


});
```

Comment: its working in jsfiddle.. am i missing something?

Comment: @patel.milanb Yes please check html value of "value attribute" using inspect element.Its still 1

Comment: for me its working fine, plus and minus symbol are incrementing and decrementing the values properly, i tried on firefox

Comment: @Giri The attribute "value" does not change on .val(), if you want to change the attribute you must use .attr()

Comment: @Anton Yes the value attribute not changing.

Comment: your HTML element doesnot have any attribute called max.. please see $qty.attr('max')

Comment: @patel.milanb  Thanks for your time. I'll use attr instead of val

Comment: @Giri You shouldn't use .attr() instead of .val() unless you must change the attribute "value" for some reason

Comment: @Giri what you want is not clear ... see this: http://jsfiddle.net/2APBa/4/ it will alert the current value of textbox

Comment: @patel.milanb This is what I want. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/2APBa/7/)  I would like to change "add to cart"  data-quantity when i click plus button. Here is the jquery code i'm using `Query(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
            $(this).parent('.quantity').next('.linkbtn02 .add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
        });
    });`

Comment: @Giri: see my answer and fiddle please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes please check html value of "value attribute" using inspect element.Its still 1 –  Giri 1 min ago

This is expected behaviour. The `value` *attribute* will always be the default value. The `value` *property* is what changes, and is what you see in the box (and is what gets submitted)

Comment: Ok Thank you for your explanation. I'll use `attr` then.

Comment: @Giri Why? `.val()` is the correct way to set an element's value.

Comment: I guess my problem is with other code. Could you check this [another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/2APBa/7/) where i added some extra code.

Comment: I want to change the add to cart button data-quantity when clicking plus button

Answer (score 1):

(I can't comment yet) Here's what's going on, when you update the value of the input, it does nothing to the actual markup that generated the interface. So when you update the quantity and you look in devTools you only see the initial value there.

This is basically what Niet said.

Also, DO NOT use attr, this is the point, `attr()` will still give the initial value, use `.val()`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2APBa/3/

Another example to show the difference between `val()` and `attr('value')`: http://jsfiddle.net/2APBa/5/

Answer (score 0):

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2APBa/8/

this is what you want..

```
 $(document).on('change', '.qty', function () {
            $('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
        });
```

as you click on `+` `-`, values changes in `.add_to_cart_button` `data-quantity` attribute

Comment: Actually my page has many items with the same structure.So I guess it will affect other elements too. Don't you think?

Comment: you should have consistent class names in your HTML structure.. otherwise yes it might affect other element data-attribute with the same class name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,

This worked very well for me.

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', Your-input-variable);
```